# How to create properties for new object types

Tags: python, objects, add-on, properties

I try to create some properties for custom primitives in property group classes and I want to access them from an operator in another `.py file` to create primitives, but I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'base'

I'm trying to follow this advice:

```
class MyProps(PropertyGroup):
        ... # properties and stuff

class ParentProps(PropertyGroup):
        # THIS WILL NOT WORK! MyProps _has_ to be registered at this point
        #foo = PointerProperty(type=MyProps)


def register():
        # 1) register property class
        bpy.utils.register_class(MyProps)

        # 2) add property (now it works)
        ParentProps.foo = PointerProperty(type=MyProps)

        # 3) register parent class
        bpy.utils.register_class(ParentProps)
```

Unfortunately I get another error:

> ValueError: register_class(...): expected a class argument, not 'tuple'

The WIP code looks like this: http://www.pasteall.org/60602/python (line 1260).

The design idea is that operators should create primitives and set up their properties, but these properties should still be there to change it later.

Comment: It would help if the example that has issues was self-contained. Currently it wont do anything - missing imports and call to register.

Answer (score 1):

```
bpy.types.Object.povcone = PointerProperty(type=RenderPovSettingsCone_add)
bpy.utils.register_class(bpy.types.Object.povcone)
```

you do not need to register a property from bpy.props like this

the property is there after the assignment and blender will use it as a wrapper for

```
obj.["povcone"]
```

so simply drop the second line

Comment: I had noticed, but this does not solve my problem: When I try to use the base property with bpy.types.Object.povcone['base'] I get an error: "    base = bpy.types.Object.povcone['base']
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str